# How to Deal with an Open HVAC Vent Blowing Hot/Cold Air in Newly Bought Home?

Tags: hvac, ventilation

I recently purchased and closed on a home and discovered an issue that wasn't caught by the general inspector. There's an open HVAC vent that blows hot or cold air depending on whether the heating or air conditioning is running. This seems inefficient and potentially problematic.

[image: open hvac vent]

I'm not sure how to approach this. Do I need to cap this vent, or are there other solutions to manage or redirect the airflow? If I need to cap it what should I use? Any advice on how to address this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There should be another open end somewhere, where that vent should connected to.  That looks like an unused attic, so heat/cold should not be needed, unless there are plumbing supply pipes that have frozen before.

Comment: @crip659 I don't see another air supply vent that this used to be connected to. It's just floating above my kitchen in the attic.

Comment: Duct could be buried in insulation...I would turn on the HVAC and see if there's a register that isn't blowing air.

Comment: No registers anywhere close to that open vent. There might have been before the remodeled, but definitely not anymore.

Comment: Are there registers in your new kitchen? Maybe they got left out during the remodel and need to be added.

Comment: @JACK no, im thinking that's what I'm going to have to do, add a register for this vent.

Comment: @terrabl the non-blowing register doesn't necessarily need to be close to that duct stub.